# PHP: Twitter button doesn't show text + link

Tags: php, twitter, hyperlink, share

This is generated Twitter button, I added text inside.

```
> <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
> src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1357735024.html#_=1357817606773&amp;count=horizontal&amp;id=twitter-widget-0&amp;lang=en&amp;original_referer=&amp;size=m&amp;text=<?php
> echo $art["title"].'
> http://web.com/article.php?art_id='.$art["id"];?>&amp;url=<?php
> echo
> 'http://web.com/article.php?art_id='.$art[id];?>&amp;via=MyWeb"
> class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-horizontal" style="width:
> 107px; height: 20px;" title="Twitter Tweet Button"
> data-twttr-rendered="true"></iframe>
```

The problem is, that I cannot add a link into the tweet. When I add it there, there is not displayed even the simple text.

Has anyone similar issue or any help, how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reorganize your code a bit just to make the building of the iframe src easier to follow (there may be a mistake there).  You should also make sure that the $art['title'] is urlencoded.

```
 <?php
    $iframe_src  = 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1357735024.html#_=1357817606773&amp;count=horizontal&amp;id=twitter-widget-0&amp;lang=en&amp;original_referer=&amp;size=m&amp;text=';
    $iframe_src .= urlencode($art['title']);
    $iframe_src .= 'http://web.com/article.php?art_id='.$art['id'];
    $iframe_src .= '&amp;url=http://web.com/article.php?art_id='.$art['id'].'&amp;via=MyWeb';
?>
 <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="<?php echo $iframe_src; ?>"  
    class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-horizontal" 
    style="width:107px; height: 20px;" title="Twitter Tweet Button"
    data-twttr-rendered="true"></iframe>
```